# Draw line automatically in jquery with the value of div tag.

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

I created two div tags and inside it, I created a span and set value of that. I need to draw line between two tags automatically using the value of span. Is it possible?

```
   <div id="lines">
       <div class="drline"><span id="num">1</span></div>
       <div class="drline"><span id="num">2</span></div>
   </div>

   <canvas id="canvas" width="350" height="300"></canvas>
```

I need to draw lines between these two tags using the value 1 and 2.

Comment: Has anybody got the question? what is meaning of `using value 1 and 2`

Comment: IDs need to be unique.

Comment: i need to draw line between those two values

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
$(".drline span").each(function(){
    if ($(this).html()==1){
      $(this).append('<div  style="border:1px solid red"></div> ');
    }
    if($(this).html()==2){
         $(this).append('<div style="border:1px solid red"></div> ');
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GRnEZ/2/)**